# What is the story behind the origin of rAga mAlkauns?

Tags: shiva, puranas, parvati

Malkauns or malkaush is one of the oldest Indian classical rAga.
Its equivalent in Carnatic music is raga hindolam.

> The raga is believed to have been created by goddess Parvati (the wife
>   of Shiva) to calm Shiva, when the lord Shiva was outraged and was not
>   calming down after Tandav in rage of Sati's sacrifice.
>
> Malkaush belongs to Shaivait musical school; in fact most pentatonic
>   ragas belong to Shaivait musical school.

Does any scripture mention of this story? Or something related to it?